# How to create a JSON file from SQL query?

Tags: python, json, sqlite

I am creating a JSON file from a SQL query. But I could not create truly. The problem is there is a "items" object and it has products. But mine create products directly not in "items" objects.

The Code.

```
import json
import collections
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT barcode,listPrice,salePrice FROM productstable")
rows = cursor.fetchall()

objects_list = []
for row in rows:
    d = collections.OrderedDict()
    d["barcode"] = row[0]
    d["listPrice"] = row[1]
    d["salePrice"] = row[2]
    objects_list.append(d)
j = json.dumps(objects_list,indent=4)
with open("products.json", "w") as f:
    f.write(j)
conn.close()
```

yields the following JSON object as a result

```
[
    {
        "barcode": "1952084972279",
        "listPrice": 100.5,
        "salePrice": 99
    },
    {
        "barcode": "1952084972280",
        "listPrice": 115.3,
        "salePrice": 100
    }
]
```

while the desired one should be as follows

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "barcode": "1952084972279",
            "salePrice": 100.5,
            "listPrice": 99
        },
        {
            "barcode": "1952084972280",
            "salePrice": 115.3,
            "listPrice": 100
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you, dear Barbaros Hocam. You made the question understandable.

Comment: you're welcome bro :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

define `objects_list` as a dictionary instead of a list.

```py
objects_list = {}
objects_list["items"] = []
```

And append to the `objects_list["items"]`.

```py
objects_list["items"].append(d)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have to work on dictionaries :)

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with SQLite code:

```
SELECT json_object("items",
         json_group_array(
           json_object(
             'barcode', barcode, 
             'listPrice', listPrice, 
             'salePrice', salePrice
           )
         )
       ) result
FROM productstable
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=25d267c5b857b2a16ad52f6c13dc0d04).
Result:

```
{"items":
  [
    {"barcode":"1952084972279","listPrice":100.5,"salePrice":99.0}, 
    {"barcode":"1952084972280","listPrice":115.3,"salePrice":100.0}
  ]
}
```

Comment: This looks nice. Can I use it for Postgre?

Comment: @HASANHÜSEYİNYÜCEL I'm sure that Postgresql has similar functions. I can check and if I find anything I will post it.

Comment: Thank you. I tried the website which you send. But it did not work.

Comment: @HASANHÜSEYİNYÜCEL Do you mean the link: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=25d267c5b857b2a16ad52f6c13dc0d04 It works for me. Try this: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4iheyW7aHsuL1vnSJJbA3k/0 also

Comment: Ahh perfect. Thank you. @forpas

Comment: @HASANHÜSEYİNYÜCEL For Postgresql it's simpler: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=eab67619ff493760f5ec8483d2f9c008 or: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oJFXFUknvSrwRo9X31M3kd/0

Comment: Very helpful :) Thanks